# MYSQL Как выполнить триггер в процедуре и через PREPARE?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Делаю так

Но, что-то не выходит, даже вне процедуры

```
SET @var = concat('DELIMITER | DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trig`; CREATE TRIGGER `trig` BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF (select count(*) from `table`)>99 THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE \'45000\';END IF;END|');
PREPARE zxc FROM @var;
EXECUTE zxc;
```

Хотя так работает

```
DELIMITER | DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trig`; CREATE TRIGGER `trig` BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF (select count(*) from `table`)>99 THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';END IF;END|
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста. В чем беда?

Comment: *Как выполнить триггер в процедуре* Никак. Выполнение триггера инициируется ТОЛЬКО как реакция на изменение данных таблицы. *через PREPARE?* Никак. Операции с триггерами недопустимы в PREPARE. *так работает* Не работает.

Comment: Мне надо создать триггер в процедуре

Comment: `Error: 1303 SQLSTATE: 2F003 (ER_SP_NO_RECURSIVE_CREATE)` - это прямо специально для Вас... нельзя, короче.